# GDB не срабатывает в Visual Studio Code

Tags: c, отладка, visual-studio-code, gdb, solus

В общем, пробовал и в основной операционной системе (использую Linux Solus) и пробовал в VirtualBox ставить, толку 0. Проходит только компиляция, а вот отладчик спит. В NetBeans IDE отладка работает, настройки IDE прилагаю.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В чем суть... Есть банальный код:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char card_name[3];
    int count = 0;

    while(card_name[0] != 'X'){
        puts("Введите значение карты: ");
        scanf("%2s", card_name);
        int val = 0;
        switch(card_name[0]){
            case 'K':
            case 'Q':
            case 'J':
                val = 10;
                break;
            case 'A':
                val = 11;
                break;
            case 'X':
                continue;
            default:
                val = atoi(card_name);
                if((val < 1) || (val > 10)){
                    puts("Я не понимаю это значение!");
                    continue;
                }
        }
        if((val > 2) && (val < 7)){
            count++;
        }else if(val == 10){
            count--;
        }
        printf("Текущий счет: %i\n", count);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Есть файлы конфигурации: **c_cpp_properties.json**

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Linux",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "/usr/include/linux",
                "/usr/include/c++/8.2.0/tr1"
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/gcc",
            "cStandard": "c11",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "gcc-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

**launch.json**

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "(gdb) Launch",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/main",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": true,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "miDebuggerPath": "/usr/bin/gdb",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

и **tasks.json**

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "echo",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "gcc",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "main.c",
                "-o",
                "main"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Сборка проходит, файл коспилируется. Через терминал всё отлично запускается. Но вот сама отладка - при включении просто крутит gdb и программа молчит.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я уже не знаю, что думать. Пересмотрел кучу всяких конфигов - толку 0. Настал критический момент, поэтому обращаюсь сюда. Прошу помощи специалистов.

Comment: А просто в терминале, `gdb main` не пробовали?

Comment: Если так напишу, либо "gdb ./main" выводит в терминал вот это - "GNU gdb (GDB) 8.2
Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
Type "show copying" and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-solus-linux".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.

For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from ./main...done.
(gdb)"

Comment: Дальше ставьте точку останова (если нужно) и запускайте (команда `r`) / А вообще,  gdb в сообщении вам подсказывает, что у него есть даже встроенный help

Comment: Не совсем пойму... в терминале отладку запускать что ли? Зачем?

Comment: Зачем забивать себе голову изучением IDE если все прекрасно работает из терминала?

Comment: Ну... как бы, если бы мне нужно было делать в терминале - я бы делал в терминале. Либо в NetBeans сидел. Но у меня конкретно суть в настройке этой отладки в VSCode. Кому что удобней - тот то и выбирает, не правда ли?)

Comment: Это вполне правильно. Я, например, даже  отладчиком редко пользуюсь (небольшая печать и размышления обычно позволяют достичь результата быстрее)

Comment: Собираете исходники с ключем `-g`? я надеюсь? или `-ggdb3` https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-help/2009-02/msg00130.html и проверять для начала легче в терминале, если там заработает, переходить в ide

Comment: Ну конечно с -g собираю, в tasks.json код прописан ведь. Я ведь говорю, отладка в IDE других работает, сборка такая же. И в QT Creator и в NetBeans работает. Я весь проект переместил в папку с англоязычным наименованием. Т.е. в пути нет кириллицы. Я думал в этом проблема... но всё равно затык остался. Не пойму, как его решить.

Comment: Посмотрите https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=webfreak.debug , может поможет

Comment: И `stopAtEntry` = `true` - Если установлено значение true, отладчик должен остановиться в точке входа цели (игнорируется при присоединении).

Comment: Да, ваше решение помогло. Установил данное расширение - отладка заработала.

Comment: Теперь сравните конфигурацию которую вам сгенерировал плагин, и сравните со своей прошлой, увидите где ошиблись.

Comment: Да, вы правы... В общем я поменял параметр **type** с  "cppdbg" на "gdb" и у меня VSCode пометил больше половины параметров зелёным подчеркиванием. Возможно, проблема была в этом. Я точно не могу утверждать, но отладка заработала...