# Visual Studio Code просмотр строк в дебагере

Tags: visual-studio-code

Если в дебагере Visual Studio Code просматривать строковые переменные (в `gfytkt watch`), вся строка не выводится, как это настраивается (и настраивается ли) ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

на скрине видно, что в конце строки `+288 more`. Если скопировать, то так и скипируется с `+288 more`

Comment: VSC довольно сырое изделие, если по существу, посмотрите плагины на замену штатному дебаг. Вероятнее всего с этой проблемой иное решение не найти.

Comment: так дебагер это и так плагин, там под каждый язык свои настройки дебагера, но такая штука со строками везде

Comment: Посмотрите эту тему, может вам поможет смена плагина генерирующего настройки дебагера https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/925487/gdb-не-срабатывает-в-visual-studio-code#comment1535573_925487